# ExecuteScript escape quote in value

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, local-storage, protractor

I am trying to create a local storage key/value pair.  When I do:

```
browser.executeScript('localStorage.setItem("groups", "[test]");');
```

I get `[test]` as the value:

[image: localstorage]

However, what I want it to be is `["test"]`

Can someone tell me how I can modify the `browser.executeScript` line in order to escape double quote characters?  I am running this in a protractor test.

I tried this:

```
browser.executeScript('localStorage.setItem("groups", "[\"test\"]");');
```

but get this error:

```
- Failed: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  In case anyone else wants to know, you have to use double slash before the double quote.

Comment: Please make sure you come back and accept this as the answer so the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!